# Unrecognized Import Path "gopkg.in/xmlpath.v2"

Tags: xml, go

I got an error when I tried to run app on my ubuntu, but when I try in Windows, It is worked.

`go: gopkg.in/xmlpath.v2@v2.0.0-20150820204837-860cbeca3ebc: unrecognized import path "gopkg.in/xmlpath.v2" (https fetch: Get https://gopkg.in/xmlpath.v2?go-get=1: net/http: TLS handshake timeout)            go: gopkg.in/sourcemap.v1@v1.0.5: unrecognized import path "gopkg.in/sourcemap.v1" (https fetch: Get https://gopkg.in/sourcemap.v1?go-get=1: net/http: TLS handshake timeout)                                  go: gopkg.in/check.v1@v1.0.0-20180628173108-788fd7840127: unrecognized import path "gopkg.in/check.v1" (https fetch: Get https://gopkg.in/check.v1?go-get=1: net/http: TLS handshake timeout)`

And here result of curl for check connection

```
*   Trying 35.196.143.184...                                         
* TCP_NODELAY set                                                    
* Connected to gopkg.in (35.196.143.184) port 443 (#0)               
* ALPN, offering h2                                                  
* ALPN, offering http/1.1                                            
* successfully set certificate verify locations:                     
*   CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt                         
CApath: /etc/ssl/certs                                             
* (304) (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):                      
* OpenSSL SSL_connect: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL in connection to gopkg.in:443                                                                    
* stopped the pause stream!                                          
* Closing connection 0
curl: (35) OpenSSL SSL_connect: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL in connection to gopkg.in:443
```

Comment: It looks like you have a problem connecting to gopkg.in.  Can you access https://gopkg.in/xmlpath.v2 in a browser?

Comment: Yes I can connecting to gopkg.in

Comment: Are you behind any kind of proxy ? What is the result of `curl -v https://gopkg.in/xmlpath.v2?go-get=1` ?

Comment: @Alper no Im not. Im using VPS Ubuntu 18.04 btw. Here is the result `*   Trying 35.196.143.184...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to gopkg.in (35.196.143.184) port 443 (#0)
* ALPN, offering h2
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
  CApath: /etc/ssl/certs
* (304) (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):`

Comment: This output is not complete. But do you see the `HTTP/2 200` or something similar ? Or do you see any kind of timeout again?

Comment: omg I forgot... this `* OpenSSL SSL_connect: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL in connection to gopkg.in:443                                                                    * stopped the pause stream!                                          * Closing connection 0
curl: (35) OpenSSL SSL_connect: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL in connection to gopkg.in:443`

Comment: There seems to be some issue with your ssl connection, you may try to update openssl maybe. Though I am not sure of the exact reason. I think the problem is related to your OS or libraries in your OS and not the package.

Comment: This may be related https://askubuntu.com/questions/1042440/ubuntu-18-04-failed-to-connect-to-some-https-sites

Comment: @Alper I have been following and disabling IPV6. And It's still not working

Comment: Well, you can search for VPS and `go get` issues. This is the only thing I can find: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/mgo-users/rO1-gUDFo_g